# Resetting a date value if it falls on weekend

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a procedure and using dynamic cursor and SQL query which I am passing as string in V_SQL variable. Query is as following:

In the where condition, I'm passing date but the condition is that if it's month end and it falls on Friday, Saturday or sunday then reset it to Thursday. for instance, 30th June will be sunday so value passed to day_of_month in SQL query should be 27 i.e. day no from Thursday date.

Could you please help me whether writing separate function will be good and what code should I put for better performance and desired result.

```
V_SQL := 'SELECT B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3, '||
'A.AS_OF_DATE, SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1 FROM DAILYGL A, AL_LOOKUP B '||
'WHERE A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = B.GL_ACCT ***AND DAY_OF_MONTH = '|| TO_DO_FUNCTION(V_RUN_DATE)***

' AND ROWNUM <=15 GROUP BY B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3';
```

DAY_OF_MONTH = '|| TO_DO_FUNCTION(V_RUN_DATE)

Desired result will be passed Thursday day number if last business day is in fri, sat or sunday.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to use dynamic SQL...? You also have a rownum filter with order-by clause or inline view, so it may not do what you expect. Anyway, what if `v_run_date` is 28th or 29th of June - those should also be adjusted to the 27th? What should happen in August - 30th and 31st should be adjusted to 29th; and 1st September is left alone?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem

```
V_RUN_DATE - (case when V_RUN_DATE > LAST_DAY (V_RUN_DATE)- 3 then  V_RUN_DATE else  
 (case TO_CHAR(date V_RUN_DATE, 'DY') when  'FRI' then 1 when 'SAT' then 2 when 'SUN' then 3 else 0 end) end)
```

Comment: This adjusts every Fri/Sat/Sun, not just those at month-end? (Also need to be aware of NLS impact of what 'DY' produces.)

Comment: @AlexPoole Added the month end condition

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a function, you can achieve this with a case expression, something like:

```
AND DAY_OF_MONTH = case
    when last_day(v_run_date) - v_run_date <= 3
      and to_char(v_run_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
      and to_char(last_day(v_run_date), 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
    then next_day(trunc(v_run_date, 'IW'), 'THURSDAY')
    else v_run_date
  end
```

That is, if `v_run_date` is within three days of the last day of the month, *and* `v_run_date` is a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, *and* the last day of the month is a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, then use the date of that week's Thursday.

Demo with dates generated for all of this year:

```
with cte (v_run_date) as (
  select date '2018-12-31' + level
  from dual
  connect by level <= 365
)
select v_run_date,
  to_char(v_run_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as dy,
  case
    when last_day(v_run_date) - v_run_date <= 3
      and to_char(v_run_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
      and to_char(last_day(v_run_date), 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
    then next_day(trunc(v_run_date, 'IW'), 'THURSDAY')
    else v_run_date
  end as adjusted_date
from cte;

V_RUN_DATE DY           ADJUSTED_D
---------- ------------ ----------
2019-01-01 Tue          2019-01-01
2019-01-02 Wed          2019-01-02
...
2019-01-30 Wed          2019-01-30
2019-01-31 Thu          2019-01-31
2019-02-01 Fri          2019-02-01
2019-02-02 Sat          2019-02-02
...
2019-03-26 Tue          2019-03-26
2019-03-27 Wed          2019-03-27
2019-03-28 Thu          2019-03-28
2019-03-29 Fri          2019-03-28
2019-03-30 Sat          2019-03-28
2019-03-31 Sun          2019-03-28
2019-04-01 Mon          2019-04-01
...
2019-04-30 Tue          2019-04-30
2019-05-01 Wed          2019-05-01
...
2019-05-28 Tue          2019-05-28
2019-05-29 Wed          2019-05-29
2019-05-30 Thu          2019-05-30
2019-05-31 Fri          2019-05-30
2019-06-01 Sat          2019-06-01
2019-06-02 Sun          2019-06-02
...
2019-06-26 Wed          2019-06-26
2019-06-27 Thu          2019-06-27
2019-06-28 Fri          2019-06-27
2019-06-29 Sat          2019-06-27
2019-06-30 Sun          2019-06-27
2019-07-01 Mon          2019-07-01
...
2019-07-31 Wed          2019-07-31
2019-08-01 Thu          2019-08-01
...
2019-08-28 Wed          2019-08-28
2019-08-29 Thu          2019-08-29
2019-08-30 Fri          2019-08-29
2019-08-31 Sat          2019-08-29
2019-09-01 Sun          2019-09-01
...
2019-11-27 Wed          2019-11-27
2019-11-28 Thu          2019-11-28
2019-11-29 Fri          2019-11-28
2019-11-30 Sat          2019-11-28
2019-12-01 Sun          2019-12-01
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=906e343059a17a607314f7d4b6caa4a3)

---

As mentioned in a comment, your code doesn't appear to need to be dynamic; you can use static SQL for what you've shown, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
-- into ...
FROM (
  SELECT B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,
    B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3, A.AS_OF_DATE,
    SUM(CURRENT_BAL) AS CB_SUM, SUM(AVG_BAL) AS AB_SUM, B.FLAG1
  FROM DAILYGL A
  JOIN AL_LOOKUP B ON B.GL_ACCT = A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID
  WHERE DAY_OF_MONTH = case
      when last_day(v_run_date) - v_run_date <= 3
        and to_char(v_run_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
        and to_char(last_day(v_run_date), 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') in ('Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun')
      then next_day(trunc(v_run_date, 'IW'), 'THURSDAY')
      else v_run_date
    end
  GROUP BY B.FIN_ELEM, A.ORG_UNIT_ID, A.GL_ACCOUNT_ID,B.CMN_COA_ID, B.PROD1, B.PROD2, B.PROD3
  -- order by something...
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 15;
```

I've also switched to ANSI joins but more importantly moved the main query into an inline view, and then applied the `rownum` filter to that; which will make no difference unless/until you add an order-by clause inside that inline view. Without it this, and your original, will get an indeterminate (not quite random, but similar effect) set of 15 rows back. If you order the inner query then you'll always get the first 15 rows according to your ordering criteria. From 12c you can use [a row limiting clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55636) instead of the subquery/rownum filter, but this approach will work in earlier versions.

Obviously you still need to either select that into variables or use it as a cursor query - whatever you had planned to do dynamically.